# Non-public API usage Flutter.framework/Flutter: _kCTFontOpticalSizeAttribute error on upload of flutter app

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

I've spent the last two days trying to submit my app to the App Store. I get the message below:

```
ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public symbols in Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: _kCTFontOpticalSizeAttribute. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/
```

Here's what Ive done so far:

a) I've scoured my code for any reference to Font Sizes - I had some that were constants - I changed the constant name to:

```
 k_fontSizeMyName
```

b) I tried to download the latest flutter sdk version
c) I rebuilt my entire keychain.

Im so desperate right now. im tired.
What do I do?

the internet has no mention of this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same message several times from the App Store Team a few minutes ago.

I think the problem was the Flutter SDK version...!

I used to use the latest version(Flutter SDK version 1.12.3-pre.26) at first but changed the Flutter SDK version to 'v1.9.1+hotfix.3' and the problem is resolved!!!

I solved the problem with the following instruction below:

> 1. Switching Flutter SDK version to 'v1.9.1+hotfix.3' with the command:
>
>    **flutter version v1.9.1+hotfix.3**
> 2. Archive and upload again ...
> 3. Problem Solved!!!!!!

Comment: Unless you know that the latest stable channel version also has this bug you can simply switch to the stable channel with `flutter channel stable` and get notified when stable is updated instead of pinning yourself to a particular version on stable.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a [recently-introduced Skia regression](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/skia/issues/detail?id=9657).

The code was included in Flutter v1.12.3, so v1.12.2 on the [dev channel](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos) should work.

Flutter's [Bad Build wiki page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Bad-Builds#v1123---v1124) will be updated when there is a fix for this issue.

**Update:** This has been resolved in Flutter v1.12.5.

Comment: Wish I could give you extra upvotes for the tip about the Bad Builds wiki page which I had not known about - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since there have been a lot of problems with flutter recently(when I tried the fix mentioned in another answer I different error) I though I should include this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/releases

Just type `flutter version [version code]`